# Mac OS - Batch Rename All Files in Folder but Disregard All SubFolders

Tags: macos, file, rename

I have a bunch of folders that I would like to rename all the files contained within minus any subdfolders.

For example lets say I have two parent folders:

```
ParentFolder1 - [PF1]
ParentFolder2 - [PF2]
```

Each parent folder has various amounts of subfolders:

```
SubParentFolder1_1
SubParentFolder1_2
SubParentFolder2_1
```

Inside the ParentFolder and each SubParentFolder there can be files such as .mp3, .txt. etc. or more subfolders.

How would I go about renaming all and any files in this manner:

```
example.mp3 -> example - [PF1]
example.txt -> example - [PF2]
example.docx -> example - [PF2]
```

Appreciate any input!

Comment: I can't tell if `[PF1]` is part of the folder name and desired file name, or if you are giving us a pointer that those are parent folders 1 and 2? There would be name clashes if you just remove the extensions as shown in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to list files (not folders) in a range of directories and then do something with them... Specifics of renaming are up to you.

```
for FOLD in Parent*; 
    do for FILE in $(ls -p $FOLD | grep -v "/"); 
      do echo "$FOLD/$FILE" "$FOLD/${FILE%.*}"; 
done; done;
```

Explanation:

For each folder (`FOLD`) in directories matching the wildcard `Parent*`, 
list the contents, adding `/` to the end of directory names. 
Do inverse `grep` on that list, leaving just the file names.
Loop through each `FILE` and echo out the original folder+file, followed by the folder and file with the suffix removed by patten matching.

Once you test this, you can replace `echo` with `mv` to do the actual renaming... (I've put these on separate lines to make them more readable, but would usually run this as one long command.